# Minimization of a combinatorial function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, combinations

The following gamma function depends on the overall sum of $x_n,x_j,x_k$

$$\gamma(X)=\sum_{x_n+x_j+x_k=X}\left [  \left ( \prod_{i=1}^{s}(x_{ni}-1)!C_i^{x_{ni}} \right )\times \binom{x_j}{x_{j1},x_{j2},x_{j3},...,x_{js}}!\times \left ( \prod_{i=1}^{s}y_i^{x_{ji}} \right )\times \binom{x_k}{x_{k1},x_{k2},x_{k3},...,x_{ks}}! \times  \left ( \prod_{i=1}^{s}z_i^{x_{ki}} \right )\right ]$$

where it is given that

$X= x_n + x_j + x_k$

$x_j = \left (\sum_{i=1}^{s}x_{ji} \right )$

$x_k = \left (\sum_{i=1}^{s}x_{ki} \right )$

$x_n = \left (\sum_{i=1}^{s}x_{ni} \right ) $

and

$x_n,x_j,x_k,x_{ni},x_{ji},x_{ki}\in \{0,1,2,3,4,..,X\}$; $y_i,z_i$ are non negative real numbers.

The function $\gamma(X)$ is computed as the sum of all possible combinations of $x_n,x_j,x_k$ such that their sum will be $X$. For example if $X=2$ then $\gamma(2)$ is computed over all possible combinations of  $(x_n,x_j,x_k)$ like (0,1,1),(1,0,1),(0,0,2) and so on.

**Explanation with example:**
Lets assume $X$=3 and $s=4$, so we have following tuples in the form of $(x_j,x_k,x_n)$  :

(0,0,3),(0,3,0),(1,2,0),(2,1,0) and so on

For each of these tuples we can write $(x_{j1},x_{j2},x_{j3},x_{j4},x_{k1},x_{k2},x_{k3},x_{k4},x_{n1},x_{n2},x_{n3},x_{n4})$

For instance tuple (1,2,0) can be written as $(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)$ and many different ways. Finally the sum is over all possible combinations of $(x_{j1},x_{j2},...,x_{js},x_{k1},x_{k2},...,x_{ks},x_{n1},x_{n2},...,x_{ns})$ for each $(x_j,x_k,x_n)$ tuple whose sum is $X$.

Is it possible to find an expression for $C_i$ which will minimize $\gamma(X)$? Is there an upper bound for $\gamma(X)$?

Comment: Do you have any control over the signs and/or magnitudes of the $x_{ji}$, $x_{ki}$, or $x_{ni}$?  You've written that their (respective) sums over $i$ are nonnegative integers, but that leaves a lot of freedom.

Comment: $x_{ji},x_{ki},x_{ni}$ belongs to the set of natural numbers {0,1,2,3,...,X}.

Comment: Then did you actually intend to write that their respective sums are _also_ restricted to that range?

Comment: That's correct. The sum is actually over all combinations of $x_{ji},x_{ki},x_{ni}$ for a given tupple of $x_j,x_k,x_n$ for a given $X$.

Comment: What is $C_i$? And are the $y_i$ and $z_i$ *nonnegative* real numbers, or any real numbers?

Comment: $y_i,z_i$ are non negative real numbers. $C_i$ is also non negative and non zero real number exists for each $i$. I'm trying to find expression for $C_i$ which can minimize $\gamma(X)$.

Comment: Now I'm less sure what you're computing.  Is $X$ specified first, then the $x_{ji}$, the $x_{ki}$, and the $x_{ni}$, which then yield the $x_j$, $x_k$, and $x_n$ via the supplied sums, OR are $x_j$, $x_k$, and $x_n$ specified first, which yields $X$ from the supplied sum and then the $x_{ji}$, the $x_{ki}$, and the $x_{ni}$ are generated as partitions of $x_j$, $x_k$, and $x_n$, which partitions are indexed by $s$?  I only ask because you have a circular definition among $X$ and $\{x_j, x_k, x_n\}$ and $s$ was never defined.

Comment: I put an example to clarify the problem. Please let me know if it's clear now. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Since $x_{ni}=0$ is permitted for some choice(s) of $i$, what do you intend to do with $(x_{ni}-1)! = (-1)!$?

Comment: Let's consider $(−1)!=1$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [edit: part] isn't really an answer; it's a proposal to reformulate the problem.  It would be helpful if @precision could verify that this formulation captures the intention.  Also, for the two questions at the end:  are the givens I've written the intended givens?  [edit: Since @precision verifies this is a valid formulation, solution attempt starts below the (re-)formulation.]

Let $X$, $s$ be positive integers.  Let $\mathscr{P}\,'$ be the set of unordered partitions of $X$ into three parts, $\mathscr{P}(p')$ for $p'=(p'_1, p'_2, p'_3) \in \mathscr{P}\,'$ be the set of all triples $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ where $p_1$ is an unordered partition of $p'_1$ into $s$ parts, and similarly for $p_2$ and $p_3$, and $\mathscr{P} = \bigcup_{p' \in \mathscr{P}\,'} \mathscr{P}(p')$.  For example, for $X=3$, $s=4$, \begin{align} \mathscr{P}\,' &= \{(3,0,0), (0,3,0), (0,0,3), (2,1,0),(2,0,1),(1,2,0),(1,0,2),(0,2,1),(0,1,2),(1,1,1)\}
\end{align} and for $(3,0,0) \in \mathscr{P}\,'$, we have these elements of $\mathscr{P}$, abbreviating "$(0,0,0,0)$" with "$0$": 
\begin{align}
\mathscr{P} \supset \mathscr{P}((3,0,0)) = \{
&((3,0,0,0),0,0), ((0,3,0,0),0,0), ((0,0,3,0),0,0), ((0,0,0,3),0,0), \\
&((2,1,0,0),0,0), ((2,0,1,0),0,0), ((2,0,0,1),0,0), \\
&((1,2,0,0),0,0), ((1,0,2,0),0,0), ((1,0,0,2),0,0), \\
&((0,2,1,0),0,0), ((0,2,0,1),0,0), \\
&((0,1,2,0),0,0), ((0,1,0,2),0,0), \\
&((0,0,2,1),0,0), ((0,0,1,2),0,0), \\
&((1,1,1,0),0,0), ((1,1,0,1),0,0), ((1,0,1,1),0,0), ((0,1,1,1),0,0)
\}
\end{align}

Now let $(J,K,N) = ((j_1, \dots , j_s), (k_1, \dots k_s), (n_1 \dots n_s)) \in \mathscr{P}$.  We immediately find $ 0 \leq j_i \leq X $ for all $i \in [1,s]$ and similarly for $k_i$ and $n_i$.  Further, we find $0 \leq j = \sum_{i=1}^s j_i \leq X $ and similarly for $k = \sum_i k_i$ and $n = \sum_i n_i$.

Finally, let $y_1$, ..., $y_s$, $z_1$, ..., $z_s$ be nonegative real numbers, $C_1$, ..., $C_s$ be positive real numbers, $Y = (y_1, \dots y_s)$, $Z = (z_1, \dots z_s)$, $C = (C_1, \dots, C_s)$, and define \begin{align}
\gamma_{X,s}(C; Y,Z)=\sum_{(J,K,N) \in \mathscr{P}} \left[  \left( \prod_{i=1}^{s}(n_i-1)!C_i^{n_i} \right )\times \binom{j}{j_1,j_2,j_3,...,j_s}!\times \left ( \prod_{i=1}^{s}y_i^{j_i} \right )\times \binom{k}{k_1,k_2,k_3,...,k_s}! \times  \left ( \prod_{i=1}^{s}z_i^{k_i} \right) \right]
\end{align}

Given $X$, $s$, $Y$, and $Z$, can we find $C$ minimizing $\gamma_{X,s}(C; Y,Z)$?  Given $X$ and $s$, is there an upper bound on $\gamma_{X,s}(C; Y,Z)$ (over the domain $(C,Y,Z) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^s \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^s \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^s $)?

### Minimization

Since the multinomial coefficients and the products involving $Y$ and $Z$ do not depend on $C$, let's reduce the "visual noise" and let 
\begin{align}
a(J,K,Y,Z) &= \binom{j}{j_1,j_2,j_3,...,j_s}!\times \left ( \prod_{i=1}^{s}y_i^{j_i} \right )\times \binom{k}{k_1,k_2,k_3,...,k_s}! \times \left( \prod_{i=1}^{s}z_i^{k_i} \right) 
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\gamma_{X,s}(C; Y,Z) &= \sum_{(J,K,N) \in \mathscr{P}} a(J,K,Y,Z) \prod_{i=1}^{s}(n_i-1)!C_i^{n_i} 
\end{align}

... and here we are stuck.  What do we mean by $(n_i-1)!$ when $n_i=0$?  (The gamma function, lurking behind the factorial, has a pole where we would want to evaluate it.  Consequently, the result is undefined if any of the $n_i$ are zero for any element of $\mathscr{P}$.)

### Spoilers

Assuming we do something not too exciting with the $(0-1)!$ instances, we will find that the sum is a homogeneous polynomial in the $c_i$, $y_i$, and $z_i$ with total degree $X$.  Every coefficient in the polynomial is nonnegative and the variables are nonnegative, so the minima/infima will occur on the (finite) boundary of the domain $(C,Y,Z) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^s \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^s \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^s $.  Whether or not $C=0$ is a global minimum will depend on what we do with the $(n_i-1)!$s.  Note that since $C=0$ is not in the domain, we will have to say something like "the value of $\gamma$ may be made arbitrarily close to the infimum, $0$, by taking $C$ sufficiently close to $0$".

Similarly, since $C, Y, Z$ are nonnegative, and the coefficients of the polynomial are all positive, $\gamma$ is unbounded -- one can always increase some element of $C$, $Y$, or $Z$ and get a larger value.

Comment: You explained the problem in an elegant way and yes, it captures the intention of the problem.

Comment: Consider $(-1)! = 1$ . Do you think if I put a bound like $0 < (C_1+C_2+C_3+.....+C_s)\leq \tau$ , I may get $C$ with at least one nonzero component. I need to get $C$ which minimize $\gamma(X)$ and which contains at least one nonzero component. Any suggestion.

Comment: I was running down the following path when I tripped over $(-1)!$:  The derivatives with respect to the $C_\ell$ are always positive, so $\gamma$ is reduced any time one of the $C_\ell$ is reduced.  In this way, the function is like a "bowl" -- low near the origin and increasing as you move away from the origin.  The only way to "fix"/change this is to get some negative numbers in somewhere.